# zodiac sign calculator using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "This is a zodiac sign calculator"
echo "May i know your name"
read name
echo "May i know your month of birth"
read month
echo "May i know your date of birth"
read date

 if ([[ "$month" == "3" ] && [ "$date" -ge "21" ]] && [[ "$month" == "4" ] && [ "$date" -le "20" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac Sign is Aries!"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "4" ] && [ "$date" -ge "21" ]] && [[ "$month" == "5" ] && [ "$date" -le "21" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Taurus"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "5" ] && [ "$date" -ge "22" ]] && [[ "$month" == "6" ] && [ "$date" -le "22" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Gemini"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "6" ] && [ "$date" -ge "23" ]] && [[ "$month" == "7" ] && [ "$date" -le "23" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac is Cancer"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "7" ] && [ "$date" -ge "24" ]] && [[ "$month" == "8" ] && [ "$date" -le "23" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Leo"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "8" ] && [ "$date" -ge "24" ]] && [[ "$month" == "9" ] && [ "$date" -le "23" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Virgo"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "9" ] && [ "$date" -ge "24" ]] && [[ "$month" == "10" ] && [ "$date" -le "23" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Libra"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "10" ] && [ "$date" -ge "24" ]] && [[ "$month" == "11" ] && [ "$date" -le "22" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Scorpio"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "11" ] && [ "$date" -ge "24" ]] && [[ "$month" == "12" ] && [ "$date" -le "21" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Saguittarius"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "12" ] && [ "$date" -ge "22" ]] && [[ "$month" == "1" ] && [ "$date" -le "20" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Capricorn"
 elif ([[ "$month" == "1" ] && [ "$date" -ge "21" ]] && [[ "$month" == "2" ] && [ "$date" -le "19" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Aquarius"

 elif ([[ "$month" == "2" ] && [ "$date" -ge "20" ]] && [[ "$month" == "3" ] && [ "$date" -le "20" ]])
 then
   echo "Hi $name !!! Your Zodiac sign is Pieces"

 else
   echo "Incorrect Input!! Try Again!"
   fi
```

Guys please help me , i am stuck here ..its showing incorrect input everytime

Comment: You require i.e. that date >= 22 AND date <= 21. There is no number which would fulfil both condition. Also, please make your code first of all syntactically correct before posting it. With what you posted, you don't get _incorrect input_, you get _syntax error_.

Answer (score 0):

I only get syntax errors. Instead of ...

```
if ([[ "$month" = 1 ] && [ "$date" -le 2 ]]) # this is wrong
```

... write ...

```
if [[ "$month" = 1 ]] && [[ "$date" -le 2 ]]
```

... or even better ...

```
if (( month == 1 && date <= 2 ))
```

If you are unsure, run your code through https://www.shellcheck.net/. Shellcheck points out problems and suggests fixes.

By the way: There is a simple trick to reduce the number of checks. If you store the month and day in a single variable having the format `MDD` and also use `elif` wisely then a single `monthdate < ...` per zodiac sign is sufficient. The following code stores both month and day in the variable `monthday` while ensuring leading zeroes for the days:

```
printf -v monthday '%d%02d' "$month" "$day"
```